# Using .toLocaleDateString() does not properly shorten month for "{month: 'short'}" if other options are included for de-DE locale

Tags: javascript, datetime, internationalization

The shortened value in German correctly returns when only the "month" option is passed in the options. Trying to also format the "day" changes how the "month" value returns. This problem is not present in `en-US` locale but is present in `de-DE`.

I am not asking for workarounds to this behavior - manually formatting the string, overriding the months, or using a datetime library are all possible solutions and are all very easy to implement. I am interested in *why* this happens.

This behavior consistently happens across Chrome, Firefox, and Node.

Changing the month to January (German: Januar) correctly shortens the month to three characters: `Jan` in both locales. Passing months with 4 letter names (May, June, July) to the `onlyMonthOption` returns 3-character strings while passing them to the `buggedOption` returns the full 4-character string when one would expect the 3-character string.

I don't think it should be expected for `month: 'short'` to return two different values depending if other options are included. It seems like a possible implementation bug.

```js
const today = new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0));
const onlyMonthOption = { month: 'short' };
const buggedOption = { month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };

//de-DE behaves unexpectedly
console.log(today.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', onlyMonthOption)); // Properly returns "Jun"
console.log(today.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', buggedOption)) // Improperly returns "Juni", expected "Jun"

//en-US works as expected
console.log(today.toLocaleDateString('en-US', onlyMonthOption)); // Properly returns "Jun"
console.log(today.toLocaleDateString('en-US', buggedOption)) // Propery returns "Jun"
```

Comment: Please note that *toLocale\** methods are **implementation dependent** and based on developer interpretations of information from the [CLDR project](http://cldr.unicode.org). It is not standardised nor in any way definitive. You are much better off to manually format dates, a library can help but is not essential.

Answer (score 1):

Germans [do not abbreviate months with 4 or less letters.  They likely find them short enough and try to avoid ambiguity.

https://web.library.yale.edu/cataloging/months

Also note that September is not sep like in many other languages

Also note you DO have a point, since according to above link, the Danish (my mother tongue) ALSO do not abbreviate four or less, but in JS they do

So my explanation is that the month alone is 3 chars and with a date it is four full or more abbreviated, that is 4 letters incl full stop. If the month has four or less letters, then no full stop.

> **German** Jan./Jän.   Feb.    März    Apr.    Mai Juni    Juli    Aug.    Sept.   Okt.    Nov.    Dez.
> **Danish** jan.    febr.   marts   april   maj juni    juli    aug.    sept.   okt.    nov.    dec.

```js
const shortMonth = {
  month: 'short',
};
const shortMonthDay = {
  month: 'short',
  day: 'numeric'
};

for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  const today = new Date(Date.UTC(2021, i, 2, 0, 0, 0));
  console.log("German month",today.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', shortMonth))
  console.log("German month day",today.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', shortMonthDay))
  console.log("Danish month",today.toLocaleDateString('da-DK', shortMonth))
  console.log("Danish month day",today.toLocaleDateString('da-DK', shortMonthDay))
}
```

Comment: This is what I expected but that doesn't explain why, when only formatting the month, it will abbreviate to 3 letters and not 4. If you check the output of your code you will see `Mär` for `month: 'short'` but `März` for `month: 'short', day: 'numeric'`

Comment: That seems to be the choice of the makers: 3 letters on their own, use 4 letters with or without full stop

Comment: I agree it seems to be how it is implemented. It was brought to my attention by a native German so it seems it wasn't following their expectations - they had expected consistent formatting of `month` regardless if additional options are passed. I would consider the 3-character abbreviation when on their own to be considered the bug since the locales do not abbreviate for 4-character month names. Thanks for the response! Now time to see where I can investigate this upstream...

Comment: I find the whole concept of "localisation" based on language tags to be fatally flawed. While certain ethnic groups commonly *write* dates in a particular language and format, they are often *published* in a variety of formats, e.g. en-GB is typically assumed to use d/m/y, yet the Times newspaper writes on its masthead dates in the format "Friday June 4 2021", which one might assume was en-US. The point is that there is no definitive format per language, and certainly not per location (locale) where one or more cultures coexist.